# Rewriting a program using functions

Tags: c, function

Does anyone know how you would rewrite the program I wrote for polynomial multiplication but this time using a function to multiply those polynomials, print the result and a function to load the coefficients of the two polynomials? This is my original code -

```
#include<stdio.h>

main ()
{
    int i, j, sizePoly1, sizePoly2;
    printf ("Enter number of terms in Polynomial 1\n");
    scanf ("%d", &sizePoly1);
    printf ("Enter number of terms in Polynomial 2\n");
    scanf ("%d", &sizePoly2);

    int a[sizePoly1], b[sizePoly2], prod[sizePoly1 + sizePoly2];
    printf ("Enter Elements of Polynomial 1\n");
    for (i = 0; i < sizePoly1; i++)
    {
        printf ("Enter x^%d Co-Efficient of Polynomial 1\n", i);
        scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    printf ("Enter Elements of Polynomial 2\n");
    for (i = 0; i < sizePoly2; i++)
    {
        printf ("Enter x^%d Co-Efficient of Polynomial 2\n", i);
        scanf ("%d", &b[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < sizePoly1 + sizePoly2; i++)
    {
        prod[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sizePoly1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < sizePoly2; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] != 0 && b[j] != 0)
                prod[i + j] += a[i] * b[j];
        }
    }
    for (i = sizePoly1 + sizePoly2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (prod[i] != 0)
        {
            if (i != 0)
            {
                printf ("%d x^%d + ", prod[i], i);
            }
            else
            {
                printf ("%d x^%d\n", prod[i], i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what I came up with. I barely understand functions so that's why it doesn't work really -

```
#include<stdio.h>

int Coef (int i, int j , int a[sizePoly1], int b[sizePoly2],){

    printf ("Enter Elements of Polynomial 1\n");
    for (i = 0; i < sizePoly1; i++)
    {
        printf ("Enter x^%d Co-Efficient of Polynomial 1\n", i);
        scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    printf ("Enter Elements of Polynomial 2\n");
    for (i = 0; i < sizePoly2; i++)
    {
        printf ("Enter x^%d Co-Efficient of Polynomial 2\n", i);
        scanf ("%d", &b[i]);
    }
}


int Polyproduct (int i, int j, int sizePoly1, int size Poly2, int a[sizePoly1, int b[sizePoly2],       int prod[sizePoly1 + sizePoly2] ){
        for (i = 0; i < sizePoly1 + sizePoly2; i++)
        {
            prod[i] = 0;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < sizePoly1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < sizePoly2; j++)
        {
                if (a[i] != 0 && b[j] != 0)
                    prod[i + j] += a[i] * b[j];
        }
        }
    }

    int PolyPrint (int i, int sizePoly1, int sizePoly2, int prod[sizePoly1 + sizePoly2]) {

        for (i = sizePoly1 + sizePoly2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (prod[i] != 0)
        {
                if (i != 0)
            {
                    printf ("%d x^%d + ", prod[i], i);
            }
                else
            {
                    printf ("%d x^%d\n", prod[i], i);
            }
        }
        }
    }

    int main ()
    {
        int i, j, sizePoly1, sizePoly2;
        printf ("Enter number of terms in Polynomial 1\n");
        scanf ("%d", &sizePoly1);
        printf ("Enter number of terms in Polynomial 2\n");
        scanf ("%d", &sizePoly2);
        Coef();
        Polyproduct();
        PolyPrint();

    }
```

Comment: `i` and `j` are only used locally, so declare them local and do not pass them

Comment: You must return a value. Lookup functions and `return` statement.

Comment: with `return` fixed, your attempt is not too bad. Also, enable warnings of your compiler.

Comment: ..and of course, when you _call_ your functions, you must pass the parameters, e.g. `coeff(sizePoly1, sizePoly2, poly1, poly2, prod)`

Comment: ..and after asking the sizes, you must declare the arrays, e.g. `int poly1[sizePoly1];`

Comment: You have mismatched brackets. You're missing the `]` at the end of `int a[sizePoly1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comments. I elaborate a bit.

Your main could look like:

```
int main ()
{
  int sizePoly1, sizePoly2;
  printf ("Enter number of terms in Polynomial 1\n");
  scanf ("%d", &sizePoly1);
  printf ("Enter number of terms in Polynomial 2\n");
  scanf ("%d", &sizePoly2);

  int poly1[sizePoly1];
  int poly2[sizePoly2];
  int prod[sizePoly1 + sizePoly2];

  Coef(sizePoly1, sizePoly2, poly1, poly2);
  Polyproduct(sizePoly1, sizePoly2, poly1, poly2, prod);
  PolyPrint(sizePoly1, sizePoly2, prod);
  return 0;
}
```

Function `Coef` should be declared as:

```
int Coef (int sizePoly1, int sizePoly2 , int a[sizePoly1], int b[sizePoly2])
{
    int i, j;
    // ...
```

With warnings turned on, you will receive some additional warnings. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for you help, I'll give it a go !